# Android: boolean not working correclty - Strange

Tags: java, android, bitmap, boolean, surfaceview

I was building a surfaceView class to display an image from the camera.  It took me a while to get it working but I added some toasts, dialogs and some boolean variables to debug it in the AnnotateSurface class and the Activity class.  I was using one of these in an if statement to run the thread to draw the image to the surface if it was true (this was what was stopping it from working).

```
if(bitmapState){

     drawSomething(canvas);
}
```

I have got it working but only after I figured out that the boolean value, bitmapState , was being reset to false.  it is initalised to false but I change it to true after in the getBitmap method. This is the only method that edits that boolean variable.

The toast in the setBitmap method displays "true", but when I call the getStuff method from the activity class it displays it as false and the if statement in the run method will also not work when I use the following:

```
if (surfaceState == bitmapState == true) {

    drawSomething(canvas);
}
```

This is really confusing as all other boolean values are behaving correctly.  If anyone has any insight I would love to hear it.

```
public class AnnotateSurface extends SurfaceView implements Callback, Runnable {

    // create a holder to manage the surface of the view
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;

    // Create a thread
    Thread ourThread = null;

    // Create a boolean to determine when to stop the animation
    boolean isRunning = false;
    boolean surfaceState = false;
    boolean bitmapState = false;

    public static Bitmap bmpIm = null;

    Context c;

    Canvas canvas;

    int ws, hs;

    public AnnotateSurface(Context context) {...
    }

    public AnnotateSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {...
    }

    public AnnotateSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {...
    }

    // create a method to pause the thread
    public void pause() {...

    }


    public void resume() {...
    }

    // create a method to resume the thread
    public void setBitmap(Bitmap b) {

        bmpIm = b;

        // bmpIm = AnnotateImage.bmpAnnotate;
        // isRunning = true;

        bitmapState = true;

        Toast toast = new Toast(c);

        Toast.makeText(c, Boolean.toString(bitmapState), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {...
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {...
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        surfaceState = false;
    }

    // @Override
    public void drawSomething(Canvas canvas) {...
    }

    public String getstuff() {

        String Data = "not drawing" + Boolean.toString(this.bitmapState)
                + Boolean.toString(surfaceState) + Boolean.toString(isRunning)
                + Integer.toString(ws) + Integer.toString(hs);

        return Data;

    }

    public Bitmap getstuffImage() {...
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {...
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, variables don't change on their own so something else is up... I noticed `bitmapState` isn't private, are you changing it in any other class? Also post where and how you create your Toasts.  Lastly, this: `Toast toast = new Toast(c);` is never used...

Comment: the Toast you were referring to can be deleted it is not used here, i declared it but never used it.  The toast under that returns true.  I am not editing it in any other class, the activity has has no boolean variables. This is the toast form the activity class ..... String tx = ourSurfaceView.getstuff();

   Toast toast = new Toast(this);
   Toast.makeText(this,tx,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I realise that I doubled up on declaring the toast there as well

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems with booleans and "if" statements in the past, the best way to deal with it is to be more explicit with them, for example:

```
if (surfaceState == bitmapState && bitmapState == true) {
drawSomething(canvas);
}
```

Cheers!
Mike

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will take use that approach in future but here I think it is the boolean variable itself here that is causing problems.

Comment: `if(surfaceState && bitmapState)` works equally well. There's never a need to explicitly compare a boolean to true.

Comment: Have you considered using some type of value holding class for your boolean?

Comment: I create a method outside of the setBitmap method that I called to change the value to true.  That did not work either.  Its annoyed me so much, I have tried quite a few variations.

Comment: Come on guys surely there is some android/java guru that may have an answer??

Comment: What about changing this.bitmapstate to just bitmap state in your getStuff method? Why is that the only one you call this. on?

Comment: Hey, that was a left over of one of the things I tried, changing all the references of bitmapState to this, bitmapState.  It must be a stupid mistake on my part but i cannot figure it out.